# Laravel listen to observers

Tags: laravel

As we know in `laravel` we can make an `observer` to listen model's interactions such as `created`,`create`,`updated` and etc.

my question is how can i `subscribe` to them without using another 3rd such as `socket` or `pusher`? is any solution to subscribe?

i tired to use `DB::listen` but i can't use that for this action

```php
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    // $query;
    // $query->bindings;
    // $query->time;
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Pusher or websockets are only required if you want to send instant browser notifications to users on your site, you don't need them if you are only going to handle the events serverside. It's not clear what your actual use case is though.

Comment: @apokryfos in observers of model how can we have listen to them outside of this class such as another controller? for example i want to listen to User observers into Home controller realtime

Comment: Not sure I understand. Model events happen within a single request lifecycle. A single request typically only gets handled by a single controller. This sounds like an XY problem, can you specify exactly what you need to do and why?

Comment: Depends where you want to use these things but use [events and listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Event Listener/Observer in laravel dispatches event based on database interaction when you interact with the database through eloquent. `socket.io` and `pusher` has nothing to do with it, they for dispatching those events in browser DOM in case you want to have a live notification to a user like a chatbox.

You can manually deploy events inside a model like below

```
namespace App\Models;
 
use App\Events\UserDeleted;
use App\Events\UserSaved;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
 
    /**
     * The event map for the model.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'saved' => UserSaved::class,
        'deleted' => UserDeleted::class,
    ];
}
```

the above code will trigger `UserSaved` class if there is a save interaction in the users table, and will trigger `UserDeleted` class if a user is deleted in users table.

Or, You can do the same thing through Observer like below

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\News;

class UserObserver
{
    
    public function saved(User $user) {
        //do something when a user is save
        News::blablabla();
    }

    public function deleted(User $user) {
        //do something when a user is deleted
        News::blablabla();
    }

}
```

You can read the docs for better explanation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events

Comment: ok, so you suppose we have 2 model such as `User` and `news`, now how can i get user triggers which defined in `User` into news controller? is it possible?

Comment: call the news method you want to run from your news model or your controller inside the user observer like my updated observer example